# How to install ruptures with Python 3.11.1 on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I created a new Python environment with 3.11.1, and installed the numpy and scipy dependencies per documentation. But then when I try to pip install ruptures it gives this error:

```
Failed to build ruptures
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ruptures, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I also tried `pip install --no-binary :all: ruptures`
And get this error:

```
pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, just downgrade the Python version to 3.10 and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).